# QCommandLineParser и QWebEngineView

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Если не использовать `QCommandLineParser`, то программа принимает опции `--remote-debugging-port=8052` и другие, что предоставляет `QWebEngineView`.

Но если забрать опции в QCommandLineParser, то получаю `: Unknown option 'remote-debugging-port'`.

Как совместить 2 парсера?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QUrl>
#include "eprinter.h"
#include <QCommandLineParser>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("webapp");
    QCoreApplication::setApplicationVersion("1.0");
    QCommandLineParser parser;
    parser.addHelpOption();
    parser.addVersionOption();
    parser.addPositionalArgument("source", "URL to open");
    parser.addPositionalArgument("printer", "Printer device (/dev/ttyS1 or /dev/usb/lp0 ...)");

    const QCommandLineOption debuggingOption(
                "remote-debugging-port",
                "Enable chrome debug at port", "port");
       parser.addOption(debuggingOption);

    parser.process(a);
    const QStringList args = parser.positionalArguments();

    MainWindow w;

    EPrinter *printer = new EPrinter(argv[1], channel);
    w.view->setUrl(QUrl(args[0]));
    w.showFullScreen();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Хочу чтоб принимались все опции Хромиума для WebEngineView, а не повторять их в своем парсере.

Например

```
$ ./webapp --no-experiments
webapp: Unknown option 'no-experiments'.
```

Comment: По идее вообще не должны мешать друг другу. Покажите ваш main.cpp

Comment: Мешают) пришлось добавить опцию вручную. Добавить все опции в хелп не получится так как там другая система с парсером

Comment: и все же покажите main.cpp, экстрасенсов тут мало :)

Comment: показал, ничего там особого)

Comment: Да уж, с такой проблемой надо к разрабам обращаться. Или мы чего-то не понимаем, или они тут что-то намутили (не первый раз).

Comment: да не, надо опцию поставить чтоб игнорировало чужие параметры. а вывести опции хрома в хелп не выйдет

Answer (score 0):

Опции хрома просто так добавить в парсер нельзя. Чтоб программа не обращала внимание на доп опции нужно заменить:

```
//parser.process(a);
parser.parse(QCoreApplication::arguments());
```